# Excel: How to delete several entire rows if some entries in these rows are duplicated only in ONE column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have spreadsheet with thousandths of rows and several columns. I want to delete all rows, with exception of one initial row, for which there are repeated values in a certain specified column.

For example: below I have 3 columns and 7 rows. I want to delete all the instances, except the first one, counting from the "bottom upwards of the spreadsheet", of the rows for which the column 1 contains the same text. In this case, row 1 should get deleted (because rows 1 and 2 both have "aa" in column 1), and also rows 5 and 6 should get deleted (since rows 5, 6 and 7 have "cd" in column 1).

So in the end I should only be left with: row 2, 3, 4, 7.

I am using Excel, Windows 10. Note that I am a complete and utter Excel noob, so I really need the simplest solution possible. I have no clue what to do and searching around on google for various solutions is confusing. Please excuse the lack of official spreadsheet terminology in my answer. I would greatly appreciate your help. Thank you.

```
aa   alex   jones
aa   tom    graham
ab   scott  paul
ba   scott  williams
cd   amy    wiggins
cd   amy    wilson
cd   frank  spencer
```

Comment: If you click the `data` tab and choose the "remove duplicates" option from the ribbon, it will walk you through exactly what to do.

Comment: Please see my response to Plato77 - "remove duplicates" doesn't help me...

Comment: Yes, sorry, I mean "delete all instances except the first one from the bottom" @Marcucciboy2

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, add an **index column** to the data set as shown below:

[image: Indexed]

**Sort** the index column from largest to smallest and **Expand the selection** to all columns:

[image: Sorted]

Highlight `Column A` and use **Remove Duplicates** function under the `Data` tab to remove duplicates as shown below:

[image: Remove Duplicates]

Then you should have the following:

[image: Result]

It is optional for you to sort the index column from smallest to largest so the data will be shown in the original order.

Answer (score 1):

If you put a further column in next to the name with the formula, which is pointing to the column that has the "aa" etc values, then say =IF(E6=E7,0,1), then it will put a 1 if the value is the one you want to keep, and a 0 if it is a value that needs deleting.  Then you can filter by this column and delete the unwanted values.  The pic below shows that I got this to work:

[image]

Comment: I think that is the wrong way round, since OP wants something that is "counting bottom upwards of the spreadsheet"

Comment: I have already tried Data>Remove duplicates, the problem is that the only duplicate values in column A are removed, but the corresponding rows as before @Plato77

Comment: On my hypothetical example I gave above, Data>Remove duplicates works, but in my real spreadsheet it doesn't. I don't understand why.

Comment: what is the criteria for retaining the bottom value?  Just because it is the last one?  Or is there a date field/other reason?

Comment: There is another reason for it, based on some other values in another column. But for the sake of the argument, let's just say "just because it is the last one"

Answer (score 1):

Here's just a quick and dirty function that assumes you have these values starting in column A.

```
Sub UniqueFromBottom()

    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Dim i As Long
    For i = Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
        If Not dict.exists(Range("A" & i).Value2) Then
            dict.Add Range("A" & i).Value2, ""
        Else
            Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: this is a very elegant solution